# Where should I put isotope('layout') in this Codyhouse script

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

I have a question and I hope someone can help me.

I'm making a website with a Codyhouse template ([link](https://codyhouse.co/gem/project-cards-template/)), and I want to load a Isotope grid on one of the portfolio pages.

But all the Isotope grid items are stacked or below each other. I think I need to re-layout the grid after one of the pages is opened, with the Isotope layout function (http://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout.html). But where in the code should I put this? I'm sorry, my Jquery/Javascript is pretty bad.

Maybe in this function? The question is, how?

```
    //open project
    projectsPreviewWrapper.on('click', 'a', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    if( animating == false ) {
        animating = true;
        navigationTrigger.add(projectsContainer).addClass('project-open');
        openProject($(this).parent('li'));

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the id of the grid in question you could do something like this:

```
//open project
projectsPreviewWrapper.on('click', 'a', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    if( animating == false ) {
    animating = true;
    navigationTrigger.add(projectsContainer).addClass('project-open');
        openProject($(this).parent('li'));
    }

    $('#yourGridIdHere').isotope('layout');
});
```

There is some pretty good documentation for Isotope, it might be worth a look

[Isotope documentation](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/)

Comment: Unfortunately I can't get this to work.

I've uploaded it here: http://howling.nl/concepts/ballroom/. Press on Gin & Tonic to view the Isotope Grid. You need to press one of the filters or resize the window before the grid sizes properly.

Do you know a way to solve this? Help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!